# qml/qt: How to get QMetaObject from QDeclarativeComponent

Tags: qt, qml

I need to receive `QMetaObject` for object that would be created by given `QDeclarativeComponent` in C++ code.

For a moment I'm solving that by using a temporary object:

```
const QMetaObject* metaObject(QDeclarativeComponent *component)
{
    QObject* object = component->create();
    const QMetaObject* result = object->metaObject();
    delete object;
    return result;
}
```

But creation of temporary object might be expensive operation and I'd like to avoid that.

Is there any way to receive `QMetaObject` from `QDeclarativeComponent` without creation of temporary object?

Qt 4.8 is being used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks impossible to me. Perhaps you can step back and solve your problem another way.